# Cloud-init: Fetch apt key from remote file instead of from a key server

Tags: cloud-init

I'm trying to add the InfluxDB (a time-series database) repository using cloud-init. The [official documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/introduction/install/#installing-influxdb-oss) states that to install it manually, the public key must first be downloaded with `wget` (or `curl`):

```bash
wget -qO- https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdb.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdb.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu bionic stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/influxdb.list
```

That works fine, and now I'd like to automate this with cloud-init.

My issue is that I don't know how to fetch the key from the provided URL before using it. I've tried this:

```yaml
apt:
  sources:
    influxdb:
      source: 'deb https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu $RELEASE stable'
```

but then I get a GPG error saying that the repository isn't signed.

I've tried the following combination of the `keyserver` and `keyid` keys without success:

- `keyserver: https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key`
- `keyserver: https://repos.influxdata.com` and `keyid: influxdb.key`
- `keyserver: https://repos.influxdata.com` and `keyid: 05CE15085FC09D18E99EFB22684A14CF2582E0C5`

How do I fetch the GPG key? I could use `Runcmd`, but I'd rather not if there's an alternative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. The key you want to import is present on the Ubuntu key server
2. The key isn't present on the Ubuntu key server

**Check if the key you want to import is part of the Ubuntu key server:**

- Get the key ID from the public key

```bash
wget -qO- https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key | gpg --with-fingerprint --with-colons | awk -F: '/^fpr/ { print $10 }'
```

- Check if it can be retrieved from the Ubuntu keyserver

```bash
gpg --keyserver=keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 05CE15085FC09D18E99EFB22684A14CF2582E0C5
```

**The key is present on the Ubuntu key server**

If it's present, then you can simply add the key ID to you cloud-init file, and mark the repository as signed by the key:

```yaml
apt:
  sources:
    influxdb:
      keyid: 05CE15085FC09D18E99EFB22684A14CF2582E0C5
      source: 'deb [signed-by=$KEY_FILE] https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu $RELEASE stable'
```

**Manually import the public key**

If the key isn't present on the Ubuntu key server, it's possible to manually import it with a `runcmd` command:

```yaml
# fetch Influx GPG public key, and store it in the keyring
runcmd:
  - wget -qO- https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/influxdb.gpg

# add Influx apt source by marking it as signed with the added key
# (note the [signed-by] option)
apt:
  sources:
    influxdb:
      source: 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/influxdb.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu $RELEASE stable'
```

Comment: At least on cloud-init 23.1.1 for ubuntu this doesn't seem to work. I believe runcmd runs after apt.  https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-init/tree/config/cloud.cfg.tmpl

Answer (score 3):

You can embed the full public key into your cloud-config file, inline.

```yaml
apt:
  sources:
    influxdb:
      source: 'deb [signed-by=$KEY_FILE] https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu $RELEASE stable'
      key: | # The value needs to start with -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
         -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
         Version: GnuPG v1

         mQINBFYJmwQBEADCw7mob8Vzk+DmkYyiv0dTU/xgoSlp4SQwrTzat8MB8jxmx60l
         QjmhqEyuB8ho4zzZF9KV+gJWrG6Rj4t69JMTJWM7jFz+0B1PC7kJfNM+VcBmkTnj
         [snip]
         -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

(Adapted from [this example in the cloud-init docs](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/22.4.2/topics/examples.html#additional-apt-configuration-and-repositories). See parts 2.8 *signed-by* and 2.9 *raw key.*)

The text from `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----` to `-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----` is the vendor's full public key, downloaded from the same URL that they told you to `wget`. (In your case, https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key.)

**Security warning**: Do *not* omit `[signed-by=$KEY_FILE]`. If you do, cloud-init will install the key into `trusted.gpg.d/`, where `apt` will treat it as globally trusted. This makes your system less secure because if the 3rd-party vendor's public key is compromised, it will affect packages other than the 3rd-party vendor's. [This is exactly why `apt-key add` was deprecated.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key/1307181) If you include `[signed-by=$KEY_FILE]`, though, cloud-init will properly store the key in a file somewhere off to the side and expand `$KEY_FILE` into the full path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `keyserver` and set it to https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdb.key

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. I tried `keyserver: https://repos.influxdata.com` with `keyid: influxdb.key`, it doesn't work either.

Comment: What's the error? Also the key ID should be set to: `05CE15085FC09D18E99EFB22684A14CF2582E0C5`

Comment: The error in both cases is that `https://repos.influxdata.com` is not a key server. The error is `Failed to obtain gpg key 05CE15085FC09D18E99EFB22684A14CF2582E0C5`.